# useEffect with many dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to fetch employees and here is what I am trying to do using `useEffect`

```
function AdminEmployees() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // fetching employees
  const { adminEmployees, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.adminFetchEmployeeReducer
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(adminFetchEmployeeAction());
    if (adminEmployees === "unAuthorized") {
      navigate("/auth/true/false");
    }
  }, [adminEmployees, navigate,dispatch]);

  console.log("Here i am running infinie loop");
  console.log(adminEmployees);
  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader></Loader>
      ) : adminEmployees === "no employees" ? (
        <h1>No Employees</h1>
      ) : (
        <>
          {adminEmployees &&
            adminEmployees.map((employee) => {
              return (
                <div className="admin__employee__container" key={employee.id}>
                  <AdminSingleEmployee
                    employee={employee}
                  ></AdminSingleEmployee>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Here I want to achieve 2 goals:

1. fetch adminEmployees
2. if (adminEmployees==='unAuthorized') then go to loginPage

but when doing this as in the code, it creates infinite loop.
How can I achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy dirty path: split `useEffect` into 2

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (adminEmployees === "unAuthorized") {
      navigate("/auth/true/false");
    }
  }, [adminEmployees, navigate]);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(adminFetchEmployeeAction());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Better way: handle that case in reducer or action creator to flip flag in the store and then consume it in component:

```
const { shouldNavigate } = useSelector(state => state.someSlice);

useEffect(() => {
  if(shouldNavigate) {
  // flipping flag back
    dispatch(onAlreadyNavigated()));
    navigate("/yourPath...");
  },
  [navigate, dispatch, shouldNavigate]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Any way i have question about `dispatch(onAlreadyNavigated)`
I faced this issue a lot and everytime I had to clean the store making action like this.
Is there a better way to do this.
because everytime i call an action, i have to clean it too, when needed.
Any better way for this?

Comment: instead of calling `navigate` directly you may put it into action creator which will do both: update flag and perform navigation

Comment: ...or you may dispatch "reset" in component which renders for route `"/auth/true/false"`